# Reactive Spring boot with SQL databases

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, reactive

I found many examples of using spring boot reactive with document databases, but none with SQL databases.

I see that it may not support sql databases yet, probably because some missing feature on the jpa/jdbc stack.

I also see that there is no point to use reactive services that depend on the a sql database with no reactive support.

The question here is: Is there any ongoing development to make this happen (reactive jpa)?

Comment: Its not a spring, JPA issue that JDBC DBs are blocking. Its an Oracle/Java concern, https://blogs.oracle.com/java/jdbc-next:-a-new-asynchronous-api-for-connecting-to-a-database is required for true reactive SQL DBs

Comment: Databases need to be reactive. I don't know any relattional database which is reactive

Comment: In general databases have their own server, so if the thread does not block waiting the sql to finish, its ok. When the sql command finishes the thread resumes, so one single web application server can process more requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reactive feature built into many RDBMSs called "Change Data Capture" which writes data to an async transaction log for an enabled table. Usually, reactive systems built to stream this data are built on top of that feature. For example, a well-known open source tool that does this is [Debezium](https://github.com/debezium/debezium). You can find other open source projects online that do something similar, or to write your own using the simple CDC functions that are usually provided to support it.